# How to get the province of a specific country?

Tags: java, xml

Is there a standard function in java library that I need to get the Region of a specific country? For now, I manually coded all the provinces of Italy. Is there any workaround that I need to use? I don't have any idea.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

https://restcountries.eu

It's an API Rest

For example, if you want to know the capital of Spain, you must do this:

```
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/spain
```

The object you get will be named ***x*** in my case:

```
var capital = x[0].capital;

alert("The capital of Spain is " + capital);
```

Answer (score 0):

None, you have to manually input it.